# "ELO Rating" and how does "TSR Rating" work?

Tags: math, ranking, evolutionary-algorithm, matchmaking

I don't know if this belongs in [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442830) or what the correct forum is, at the very least it could be used as a fitness model for evolution of algorithms, or perhaps as a matchmaking algorithm for a specific player ranking in team based games. So I'm also posting this here as programming is also a subset of mathematics, especially considering how much the Elo is in use.

---

I was a member of a DotA 1 community that transitioned from a ["Elo ranking system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), to a new ranking system named "TSR"; that community and it's website died over a year ago and I can no longer find any information regarding it's calculation. From my experience this TSR system was more accurate than Elo, it would be a shame if this was lost.

Does anyone know how to calculate TSR according to the "TSR Ranking System"?

Here is an internet archive of the site where there was some literature on the subject, However I cannot find the exact page in question. http://web.archive.org/web/20110923152416/http://www.dotacash.com/index.php?p=news

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing the people who maintained this system?  On what basis was it said to be superior, and in what way?

Comment: From Experience, I played many games and it just felt more accurate in terms of how difficult the game was, in terms of my and the opposing teams players' rankings. Also There is this https://entgaming.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=68516